# Slow custom order search SQL query in WooCommerce

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

On a website with roughly 10k orders, our order search takes on average 20 seconds to complete while searching for order number. This is the sql-query that is slow

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p1.post_id
FROM nb_postmeta p1
WHERE p1.meta_value LIKE '%ordernumber%'
AND p1.meta_key IN ('_billing_address_index','_shipping_address_index','_billing_last_name','_billing_email','_billing_phone')
```

Is there any change I could make to this query to speed it up?

I tried cleaning up the database with a number of plugins, turning off most plugins, but query monitor leads me to this specific query every time as the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Make sure meta_key and meta_value columns are indexed. If you don't already have a clustered index, then adding a clustered index on meta_key might help. Although, a clustered index could slow down other queries.

@LoicTheAztec is correct that the LIKE is probably slowing things down a lot. It would help if you could get rid of the first % - LIKE 'ordernumber%' - especially if you add an index to meta_value. Make sure the query isn't being run every time someone types a letter in the order number.

The in() is probably slowing things down. If the list of items in the in() are fixed, it would be faster to create a table named something like nb_postmeta_search_meta_keys that has a single row for each value ('_billing_address_index','_shipping_address_index','_billing_last_name','_billing_email','_billing_phone'). Add a unique, clustered index to that field and join nb_postmeta to the new table.

The DISTINCT might be slowing things down. You could try switching to a GROUP BY:

SELECT p1.post_id
FROM nb_postmeta p1
WHERE p1.meta_key IN ('_billing_address_index','_shipping_address_index','_billing_last_name','_billing_email','_billing_phone')
GROUP BY p1.post_id, p1.meta_value
HAVING p1.meta_value LIKE '%ordernumber%'

Moving the LIKE to HAVING should speed things up since the WHERE will be applied first. I don't know the data so I'm not sure if it will give you the results you need. (I don't know anything about WooCommerce). You might not have to do all of these things. Do the easiest things first and see how much it helps. A reasonably powered db server should be able to return results on 10k records very quickly if the SQL is optimized.